# save image in public folder instead storage laravel 5

Tags: php, sql, database, image, laravel

i wanna save my avatar at "Public" folder and ther retrieve.

ok. i can save it but in "storage/app" folder instead "public"

my friend told me go to "config/filesystem.php" and edit it ,so i did it like this

```
 'disks' => [
   'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('image'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/public',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

still no change.

here my simple codes

Route :

```
Route::get('pic',function (){
return view('pic.pic');
});
Route::post('saved','test2Controller@save');
```

Controller

```
public function save(Request $request)
{
        $file = $request->file('image');
        //save format
        $format = $request->image->extension();
        //save full adress of image
        $patch = $request->image->store('images');

        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();

        //save on table
        DB::table('pictbl')->insert([
            'orginal_name'=>$name,
            'format'=>$base,
            'patch'=>$patch
        ]);

        return response()
               ->view('pic.pic',compact("patch"));
}
```

View:

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'saved','method'=>'post','files'=>true]) !!}
                {!! Form::file('image') !!}
                {!! Form::submit('save') !!}
            {!! Form::close() !!}

                <img src="storage/app/{{$patch}}">
```

How Can save my image (and file in future) at public folder instead storage?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In config/filesystems.php, you could do this...
change the root element in public

```
'disks' => [
   'public' => [
       'driver' => 'local',
       'root'   => public_path() . '/uploads',
       'url' => env('APP_URL').'/public',
       'visibility' => 'public',
    ]
]
```

and you can access it by

```
Storage::disk('public')->put('filename', $file_content);
```

Comment: i just copy your comment and here my error : "Driver [] is not supported." of course driver is "local"

Comment: tnx bor. i just create new project and change config and finally it work'd.

Comment: How to get the $file_content variable easily ? I can't understand why it's so complicated to store a file using a framework...

Comment: I had to change this line to `env('APP_URL').'/public/uploads',`

Comment: I am adding the filename but it creates a folder with that name instead, do you know why?

Comment: @GonzaloFS  you need to provide the file contents in the second argument not file object, try this:

    `Storage::disk('local')->put($newFilename, file_get_contents($file));`

Answer (score 16):

You can pass disk option to method of `\Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile` class:

```
$file = request()->file('image');
$file->store('toPath', ['disk' => 'public']);
```

or you can create new Filesystem disk and you can save it to that disk.

You can create a new storage disc in `config/filesystems.php`:

```
'my_files' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root'   => public_path() . '/myfiles',
],
```

in controller:

```
$file = request()->file('image');
$file->store('toPath', ['disk' => 'my_files']);
```

Comment: It's crazy how complicated that is compared to good old `file_put_contents()`

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to [link your storage directory to your public folder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#the-public-disk) with:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Once you've done that, to display it in the view you can do:

```
{{ asset('storage/file.txt') }}
```

Or in your case:

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/app/' . $patch) }}">
```

Comment: i did but nothing. here my full address of image => "http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/app/images/MSJ3rDIyt0f6ozKrrQtYtkcoZmJvgE80VYdFl20d.png"   and this file exist but not shown.     i just need to save files into public folder or somehow move images to public

Comment: This answer will work with default public file configuration. I'd change your `public` array back to default and save you file again.

Comment: you mean "filesystems.php"? but the why don't work for me? confused

Comment: Is the file you uploaded in the `public/storage/images/` folder? If not, you're not saving it correctly and it won't show up without a lot more work. But if you follow my answer and revert `filesystem.php` to default, it will start working.

Comment: my file uploaded in here "my-Project_folder/storage/app/" but i wanna upload here "my-Project_folder/public/"  and my filesystem.php is default now but no change.  here my filesystems content " 'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
php artisan storage:link
```

when store file

```
$path = $request()->file('file')->store('images', 'public');
```

> path = domain/storage/images/filename.txt

> file will save in storage/app/public/images

Comment: I'm using Laravel 9 and this worked correctly to place files in the storage/public directory.  Using php artisan storage:link makes the storage/public directly accessible from the web. I am using VueJS to pull images from storage and it works great using :src="`/storage/${image.file_path}`"