# Save cropped image in the public/uploads folder with laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to upload the image I cropped to the public/uploads folder in laravel.
I am able to save the image path to the database, but I am not able to save the cropped image to the public/uploads folder.

This is how my code looks like:

```
 $slideshow = \App\Slideshow::find($id);
        //This is the path to the image that's in the database.
        $pieces = explode("/", $slideshow->image);
        $image = $pieces[0]. "/public/". $pieces[1]. "/". $pieces[2];
        $new_image = $pieces[0]. "/public/". $pieces[1]. "/". $pieces[2];
        $image_quality = '95';
        list( $current_width, $current_height ) = getimagesize($new_image);


        //This is the data that gets send from the blade form
        $x1 = $request->input('x1');
        $y1 = $request->input('y1');
        $x2 = $request->input('x2');
        $y2 = $request->input('y2');
        $width = $request->input('width');
        $height = $request->input('height');

        //This function is cropping the image
        $crop_width = 50; 
        $crop_height = 50;
        $new = imagecreatetruecolor( $crop_width, $crop_height );
        $current_image = imagecreatefromjpeg( $new_image );
        imagecopyresampled( $new, $current_image, 0, 0, $x1, $y1, $crop_width, $crop_height, $width, $height );
        imagejpeg( $new, $new_image, $image_quality );
        $final_image = imagejpeg( $new, $new_image, $image_quality );

            if($final_image == true) {
                $image = 'uploads/' . $image['image'];
                $final_image = 'uploads/crop_'. $pieces[2];
                $destination = '../uploads/';
                $complete = $destination.$final_image;

                $slideshow->cropped_image = $complete;
                $slideshow->save();

                Storage::copy($image, $final_image);
                dd(Storage::copy($image, $final_image));

                return redirect()->back();
            } else {
                dd('Doesn't work');
            }
```

After the crop function I am trying to put the cropped image into a variable and then putting the image in the public/uploads folder.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! :)
I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42562203/save-image-in-public-folder-instead-storage-laravel-5) may have some answers than will help you. I believe Laravel's `Storage` facade stores files in the `storage/app` directory by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would really recommend using image intervention package which is extremely handy and clean in such implementations.

See [here](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation#laravel) for installation, its pretty straightforward.

And then to crop you can easily use [crop](http://image.intervention.io/api/crop) functions  of the package :

```
<?php 

    $originalImagePath = '//your_image_path'
    $x = $request->input('x');
    $y = $request->input('y');
    $width = $request->input('width');
    $height = $request->input('height');

    $croppedImage = Image::make($originalImagePath);              
    $croppedImage->crop($width, $height, $x, $y);
    $croppedImage->save('//new_path_here');
```