# How to change the storage path of files?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I want to change the storage path of my data (files) from the default `storage/app/public` to `public/files.`

**Controller**

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    request()->validate([
        'filename' => 'required',
    ]);

    $files = $request->file('filename');

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        File::create([
            'filename' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
        ]);
    }

    return redirect('/file')->with('success', 'File Uploaded Successfully');
}
```

Comment: This question is already resolved

Answer (score 0):

go to config folder -> filesystems.php

```
'public' => [
      'driver' => 'local',
      'root' => public_path(),
      'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
      'visibility' => 'public',
 ],
```

```
public function upload(Request $request)
    {
      $uploadedFile = $request->file('filename');
      $filename = time().$uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName();

      Storage::disk('local')->putFileAs(
        'files/'.$filename,
        $uploadedFile,
        $filename
      );

      $upload = new Upload;
      $upload->filename = $filename;
      $upload->save();

    }
```

Comment: i changed it to this,,, 'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('public/files'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ], but now i dont know where is my data is saving,,,,,because both folders are empty but files are saving in db and showing in browser

Comment: Did you check storage folder?

Comment: Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on array

Answer (score 0):

```
          $fileFullName=$request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalName();

        $fileName=pathinfo($fileFullName,PATHINFO_FILENAME);

        $ext=$request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileToSave=$fileName.'_'.time().'.'.$ext;
        $store=$request->file('cover_image')->storeAs('/public/cover_images',$fileToSave);
```

Answer (score 0):

in your config/config/filesystems.php you can do this like:

```
'disks' => [

   'uploads' => [
     'driver' => 'local',
     'root'   => public_path() . '/uploads',
     'url' => env('APP_URL').'/public',
     'visibility' => 'public',
   ],

]
```

and then store like this:

```
Storage::disk('uploads')->put('filename', $file_content);
```

Comment: also check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42562203/save-image-in-public-folder-instead-storage-laravel-5